# How can I easily access a Hash value embedded in an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm facing I guess a basic issue, but I can't find a better way to 
deal with it.

I have an Array:

```
a = [ { "address_number" => 123, 
        "suite"=> 342, 
        "crazy_hash" => true, 
        "crazy_hash" => [{"why_hash_in_array" => true}] 
      }, 
      "I'm a string", 
      123, 
      { "empty" => ""} 
    ]
```

I want to access the Hash with the key "why_hash_in_array", and am 
doing this:

```
b = a.first["crazy_hash"].first["why_hash_in_array"]
```

I understand that this is not a good way to access the data because if 
the array changes the order, the retrieval of that key will not work 
anymore.

Is there a method from Ruby or Rails that can "magically" retrieve 
that keypair? Something like:

```
a.magic_hash_wand["why_hash_in_array"] 
=> true
```

Comment: You have two keys with same name, why?

Comment: He can't have two with the same name, so it has to be a mistake.

Comment: That's an example. Regardless of "crazy_hash" being repeated, the issue is still there.

Comment: Any solution to this problem will be a bad solution. In other words: "You're doing it wrong". If you provide more info on what you're actually trying to do, we can tell you how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a magic chain that will help you :-)

```
puts a.map{|b| b["crazy_hash"] rescue nil}.compact.flatten.first['why_hash_in_array']
# => true
```

It's immune to array reordering and will return first `crazy_hash` it sees. If that `crazy_hash` is not a hash, it will raise an error.